# Can't insert python list data into database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python list type data

```
country = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to insert this list into a database table- in a row like this

```
country =  [('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

So i have written code:

```
import sqlite3
from collections import Counter

db = "test.db"

conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE country_data (country TEXT)")

country = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']

c.execute("INSERT INTO country_data VALUES(?)", (str(list(Counter(country).items()))))

conn.commit()
```

But it gives me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "try.py", line 19, in <module>
c.execute("INSERT INTO country_data VALUES(?)", (str(list(Counter(country).items()))))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 30 supplied.
```

How can i solve this??

Comment: Well, I can tell you where the error is coming from at least. The length of the string returned by that expression is 30. So I'm guessing it's not expecting a string like that. I don't know enough about the sqlite3 library to tell you what it does need, unfortunately.

Comment: If i remove str() and write only


`list(Counter(country).items())`


 Error is:
`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.`

Comment: Your table consists of exactly one column. How do you hope to store `('a', 3)` in a single column? Or do you mean you want three rows of `a`, two rows of `b` and one row of `c`?

Comment: @Robᵩ no i want to store this full country list into a column like above. Is possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a table that can store your numbers:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE country_data(country TEXT, cnt int)")
```

Next, you need just a list of tuples:

```
data = list(Counter(country).items())
```

And then, you can insert the data into your table with executemany:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO country_data(country, cnt) VALUES(?,?)", data)
```

Note two ? in INSERT - one for every value.

---

OK, I've read you're comment now. It turns out that all you want is to put a string into your text column.
You fell into a little trap. It just happen that your string was unpacked into 30 letters. Wrap it into explicite tuple. It may look like this:

```
data = str(list(Counter(country).items()))
c.execute("INSERT INTO country_data(country) VALUES(?)", (data,))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(str(list(Counter(country).items())))` is not a tuple, it's just `str(list(Counter(country).items()))`. You need a tuple with one element which is specified by a trailing comma: `(str(list(Counter(country).items())), )`.

Comment: I have tried like this but it gives me same error :(

Comment: @Fahim I think you got mixed up by your parentheses. Try `country_string = str(list(Counter(country).items())); c.execute("INSERT INTO country_data VALUES(?)", (country_string,))`.